# Replacing QT with OPENCV for Face Recognition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, opencv, face-recognition

I have a face recognition program. Its basics are in opencv but GUI is in QT. I want to change the GUI to opencv. How can I do? Like What is the reciprocal class for QWidget in OpenCV?
Any document or link will be help full. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you seem to be confused about what does what here. opencv probably does the face-recognition, Qt does the gui. try to seperate those as much as possible

Comment: Please see the question again. I changed it.

Comment: there are no real widgets in opencv. the highgui module has a window you can use for showing images, and that's about it. (extended gui was probably the reason for choosing qt in the 1st place). but i *can* understand your problems decoupling this.

Comment: people use both quite often.

Comment: you can try imshow() in combination with waitKey().. to display images/videos using Opencv's Highgui library.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have some confusion on the role of the two:

openCV is a computer vision library, **not an application and GUI framework**

Put simply: with Qt you can create graphical interfaces that run on many platforms and expand those using OS wrappers

openCV is a series of APIs designed to operate on image data to do image recognition, image processing and, in general, all the tasks and operations that fall under the "computer vision" umbrella term

**TL;DR - they serve different purposes, your question as it stands makes little sense**

Comment: Please see the question again. I changed it.

Comment: There's no equivalent of QTWidget in openCV, they're two different things. QTWidget is a graphical widget into a Qt window/app, there's nothing in openCV like that